# How to use types to enforce specific pairs of parameters?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a service responsible for generating different types of charts.

The space of charts that can be generated has two dimensions, `chartType` and `dataType`, which are both finite sets of values, something like this:

```
enum ChartType {
  ChartTypeA,
  ChartTypeB,
  ChartTypeC
}

enum DataType {
  DataTypeA,
  DataTypeB,
  DataTypeC
}
```

The service exposes a single public method, `generateChart(chartType: ChartType , dataType: DataType)`, which then calls the relevant private method depending on what `chartType` is passed in.

The exact implementation of the private method depends on the other parameter, `dataType`.

So far so good.

My problem is the following, some combinations of `(ChartType, DataType)` are not possible (I.e. I can't generate a chart with `ChartTypeA` and `DataTypeC`), which makes me question my current implementation.

What is a better way to organise my data so that the compiler can enforce that only possible pairs of parameters are passed to the function?

Comment: Do you have any pattern which does not match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overloads for each possible valid combination:

```
enum ChartType {
    ChartTypeA,
    ChartTypeB,
    ChartTypeC
}

enum DataType {
    DataTypeA,
    DataTypeB,
    DataTypeC
}

function generateChart(chartType: ChartType.ChartTypeA, dataType: DataType.DataTypeA)
function generateChart(chartType: ChartType.ChartTypeC, dataType: DataType.DataTypeC)
function generateChart(chartType: ChartType.ChartTypeB, dataType: DataType.DataTypeB)
function generateChart(chartType: ChartType, dataType: DataType) { // Implementation signature

}

generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeA)
generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeC) // Error
```

Or we can use a mapping type to cut down the ceremony a bit:

```
interface EnuMap  {
    [ChartType.ChartTypeA]: DataType.DataTypeA,
    [ChartType.ChartTypeB]: DataType.DataTypeB,
    [ChartType.ChartTypeC]: DataType.DataTypeC,
}

function generateChart<T extends ChartType>(chartType: T, dataType: EnuMap[T])
function generateChart(chartType: ChartType, dataType: DataType) { // Implementation signature

}

generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeA)
generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeC) // Error
```

**Note** If we use an interface for the mapping type, the interface can be extended as needed by a plugin for example if it ads support for a new combination of types.

**Edit**

If most combinations are possible and only a few should be excluded we could use a different approach. First create a type that contains all possible combinations of parameters and the use `Exclude` to take out the imposible combinations:

```
function generateChart<T extends Excluded>(...a: T)
function generateChart(chartType: ChartType, dataType: DataType) { // Implementation signature

}
type AllCombinations = {
    [C in ChartType]: {
        [D in DataType]: [C, D]
    }
}[ChartType][DataType]
// Exclude unwanted combinations
type Excluded = Exclude<AllCombinations, [ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeC]>; 

generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeA)
generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeB, DataType.DataTypeA)
generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeC) // Error
```

We lose a bit of expresivness with this approach in parameter names and the overloads the compiler suggests (just a code completion thing, it works as expected)

A solution that plays nicer with intelisense and keeps parameter names could be constructed using `UnionToIntersection` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type). We first create a union of all possible signatures and then we use `UnionToIntersection` to create a function with all overloads.

```
type AllCombinations = {
    [C in ChartType]: {
        [D in DataType]: [C, D]
    }
}[ChartType][DataType]
type Excluded = Exclude<AllCombinations, [ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeC]>;
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type SignatureHelper<T> = T extends [infer C, infer D] ? (chartType: C, dataType: D) => void : never;
type GenerateChartType = UnionToIntersection<SignatureHelper<Excluded>>
const generateChart:GenerateChartType  = (chartType: ChartType, dataType: DataType) => { // Implementation signature

}
generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeA)
generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeB, DataType.DataTypeA)
generateChart(ChartType.ChartTypeA, DataType.DataTypeC) // Error
```

Comment: Interesting, the first solution could certainly be an option. What if the space was much bigger, with just a few impossible combinations? That would force me to overload every possible pair. The second solution looks more like what I had in mind, give me a second to try and understand it.

Comment: @bugs The second option is the same, not much of a difference except syntax. Let me see if we can do a cartesian product between the two enums and then eliminate the extra ones ..

Comment: @bugs Added more versions, the types get a bit complicated but the last oe works out nice in my opinion. Let me know if I can help with anything :)

Comment: Great, just having a look at everything now